# Twitter Event Without Data

Tags: javascript, events, twitter

I am adding a Twitter Follow button to a website. This is the piece of HTML.

```
 <div id="twitter-follow"> 
    <a class="twitter-follow-button"
      href="https://twitter.com/<some name>"
      data-size="large">
    Follow @<some name></a>
  </div>
```

When a user press the follow button I want to be able to retrieve the Twitter user ID. For this I have been following the documentation here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/javascript-api. However, the data object in the event I do receive doesn't have the user id.

This is the javascript that handles the event:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
      var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
      js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
  </script>
  <script>
  twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('follow',   function(e) {
       console.log(e)
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I do think I am missing something like asking the user authorization for gathering sensible data.
Does anyone know why I am not getting the user ID if the documentation says I should get it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After more digging, I realized that the user id or the screen name that the event handles in the data object are the ones you provide to the Twitter indent.

There is no way we can retrieve the id from the user is actually clicking in the following button :-(